# To see the response coming from a wcf service

Tags: .net, wcf, exception, runtime-error

When I am hitting a page, it is showing error like :

> Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'.

in a line, where we are calling a method from wcf service.

Now I want to see what exactly the response coming from that wcf service, OR what exactly is going wrong in the service.

Is there a way to find this out..using some fiddler or so??

Comment: What **binding** is your WCF service using? If you use `webHttpBinding`, then it's a **REST** service and then yes - use Fiddler to investigate the HTTP traffic. If you're using any other binding, then it's a **SOAP** service, and you should use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) or a similar tool to monitor SOAP traffic

Comment: I am using basicHttpBinding ..

Comment: That's **SOAP** --> go get SoapUI !

Answer (score 0):

***If you have aceess to the server side***, consider service level logging. You should be able to log whats going on to a text file or to a db table using a logging framework of your choice by enabelling Message Logging.

Pls refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx for more details.